# Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/

Tags: android, cordova

I get some error messages in Logcat when running my Android App, which was built using PhoneGap.

```
E/AndroidProtocolHandler(1475): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/css/mobile2.css
E/AndroidProtocolHandler(1475): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/scripts/custom.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler(1475): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/scripts/customShare.js
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check the path (where you are trying to access it) to insure that it is correct.  You could also check the permissions on the file to insure that you can read/ write to the file.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You helped me so much - i'm so stupid - my folder was Css and not css.

Comment: I don't think it really matters as long as you stay consistent @IamStalker

Comment: @JoePacker I've changed only folders to lowercase and it's started running.

Comment: @IamStalker great to hear

Comment: @JoePacker Thanks mate if I could rise your score for more that +1 I would.

Comment: how do I change the path though?

Answer (score 12):

If this error persist after adding permission then check case of file names

as

> **file names are Case Sensitive in phonegap app**

Comment: What I needed to do was lower case my file names, even tho I was referring to them with correct capitalization. FileName.txt => FileName.txt but it didn't work. I had to filename.txt => filename.txt

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was a underscore as a first letter in a folder name. I had:

```
file:///android_asset/html/_js
```

which I renamed to:

```
file:///android_asset/html/js
```

That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue and i have solved 
first i have placed my new.js file in **asset-->www-->js-->new.js**

after that i cut that file and placed in **asset-->www-->new.js**
Now its working fine hope its help for you

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem like you and I could not access and play video file from assets or raw file. After trying many more solution getting online, I could not resolve my problem. But,I have solved my problem by storing video file into mobile storage. Like:

```
<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src=“file:///storage/emulated/legacy/Video/test.mp4”  type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Note: `“file:///storage/emulated/legacy/Video/test.mp4”`  information will be changed as per your storage location.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all options above but the issue still persisted.

Here was the fix that I figured out:

Go to Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters
and remove the Exclusion filters.

This should rebuild automatically and you'll be fine.

Comment: Where is Project located in Android Studio?